# Firebase and Crashlytics - Which one to use?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, firebase-crash-reporting

Since the presentation of Firebase Crash Reporting, one of the most prominent questions has been wether moving from Crashlytics or not.

What are the pros and cons when comparing the two crash reporting services?

Comment: Since this question is subjective in nature (and quickly becomes obsoleted as new features are added), it doesn't really belong on SO.  However, Quora is a great place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 22):

There are pros and cons, as listed below, when considering the switch between the two.

**NOTE**: <strike>Firebase Crash Reporting is currently labeled as `beta`, and Google is still collecting early feedback in order to improve the service. So things that are missing now are most likely to be added in the near future.</strike> (no longer in Beta as of Nov 7th 2016)

**Pros**

- Both ordinary <strike>and native crashes</strike> (It seems native crashes are only visible in Crashlytics@Fabric console for now) are displayed in Firebase
- Automatically integrates with Firebase Analytics, which enables grouping users that experienced crashes into an audience and gives context (through events) to the crash
- Dead-easy setup (just include the Gradle module)
- All-in-one console with other Firebase products (if you plan on using them)
- [Lower number of methods](http://www.methodscount.com/?lib=com.google.firebase%3Afirebase-crash%3A%2B) (even though it includes Analytics, using the standard methods allows ProGuard to strip almost everything, so props to Google for that)
- Possible to turn off gathering analytics on a per-user basis [thanks [racs]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480790/firebase-and-crashlytics-which-one-to-use/37480793?noredirect=1#comment62606126_37480793)
- Sends notification emails for new and regressed issues (as Fabric does)

**Cons**

- Searching through crashes is not available
- ProGuard/DexGuard mapping files have to be uploaded manually (Google is on this)
- Impossible to have a listener in the session just after a crash occurred
- Requires Google Play Services on the device (big requirement) [thanks [Gerrit Hoekstra]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480790/firebase-and-crashlytics-which-one-to-use/37480793?noredirect=1#comment62512167_37480793)

---

All in all, Crashlytics is much more feature complete, but Firebase is about to catch up on a lot of stuff. Both are free, so that is not an obstacle.

**UPDATE 09/12/2016**

I've updated this answer thanks to the inputs of [Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4520913/ali-abdelhadi).

Comment: Note that Firebase requires Google Play services 9.0 or later to work correctly. Crash Reporting will not init with earlier versions. Crashlytics doesn't require Google Play services. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37393218#comment62356275_37393218

Comment: True, I'll add that to the list. Thanks!

Comment: Cons: you won't get notification emails from Firebase about new crashes and daily summary. I have found that very useful in Crashlythics. Pros: it is possible to turn off gathering analythics on per-user base in Firebase, while there is no control over what is collected and when by Crashlythics.

Comment: Currently Crashlytics has got a big issue: it does not support JACK that means for example that you can't use lambdas

Comment: @kingston You can use retrolambda.

Comment: Note: Crashlytics will soon become the primary crash reporter for Firebase. If you aren't already using Crash Reporting to report crashes and non-fatal errors in your app, we recommend using Crashlytics.

Comment: Cons: native crashes are not visible on Firebase (works with Crashlytics@Fabric) but does not work on Crashlytics@Firebase

Answer (score 6):

Here are some updates since Sebastiano's answer:

- Firebase Crash Reporting is no longer in Beta as of Nov 7th
- New Analytics integration allows you to see Analytics events as a part of a crash report so you have context on what happened
- It is now possible to mark a crash as closed
- Firebase now sends notification emails for new and regressed issues
- Plugin to automatically upload mapping files will be available soon
- Native crashes are actually not supported but we’re working on it

(I work on Firebase Crash Reporting)

Comment: Thanks for the update! May I update my original answer with your contributions?

Comment: How is the speed of crash reports now? One of the big benefits of Crashlytics, IMO, is that you get crash reports within a few minutes of them happening. This is hugely valuable in my experience when rolling out new versions using Crashlytics.

Comment: Firebase reports crashes in less than a minute now.. usually within a few seconds.

Comment: @AliAbdelhadi Does firebase also allow building "context" of logs prior to a crash so that we can get "deep background" when a crash occurs? Crashlytics has a .log() method, but it sometimes "forgets" to attach those messages to the crash report. Reference: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html?#custom-logging

Comment: Apologies for not seeing this earlier. Yes, Firebase does offer a logging function, and even more, it automatically imports Firebase Analytics events into the crash report for additional context.

Comment: @AliAbdelhadi since Crash Reporting is out of beta, is there a way to allow the user to disable it by having a settings option in the app? Something similar to what analytics has?

Comment: Not at the moment, but it's something we're closely looking into. Hope to have an update on this soon.