# enable Firebase Crash Reporting in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I followed all steps from  https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android to implement Firebase Crash report. But I'm not able to see my crash report on Firebase console.

In Android studio's logcat its showing me :

> V/FirebaseCrash: Firebase Crash Reporting is disabled.

I don't understand how to enable Crash reporting. I also referred [How to enable Firebase Crash Reporting - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393218/how-to-enable-firebase-crash-reporting-android) 
But nothing is helping me out.

I used their own code to throw an exception to see if it works:

```
  try {
    throw new NullPointerException();
} catch (NullPointerException ex) {
    FirebaseCrash.logcat(Log.ERROR, TAG, "NPE caught");
    FirebaseCrash.report(ex);
}
```

Project Gradle :

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

App Gradle :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "medimanage.corporate.mobile"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 3
            versionName "2.2"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }

        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
        compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
        compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
        compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar'
        compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
        compile files('libs/android-error-reporter.jar')
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.0'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you added the google-services.json? Can you check for other FirebaseCrash messages in the log (e.g. "Application context is missing, disabling api" or "Failed to initialize crash reporting")

Comment: Also make sure your device has Play services installed.  This means that only emulator images with "Google APIs" will work.

Comment: I was having the same error and I solved it as here [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354611/error27-13-failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-8-0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error

> V/FirebaseCrash: Firebase Crash Reporting is disabled.

happens when the device or emulator doesn't have Google Play services **9.6.x** installed.