# Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to use Firebase in my app.

After adding three lines to Gradle, I get this error:

> Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0

Here are some images of my code:

[image: this is in the application Gradle]
[image: this is something else]
[image: this is in the application Gradle]

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: did you add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' in gradle

Comment: yeah I already Added it

Comment: and did you added         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
 in project gradle

Comment: ' apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'       '

Comment: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'

Comment: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Comment: I addded these 3 lines to the code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure the Google Repository and its related repostories has been updated to the latest version. Check by going to the SDK Manager -> Extras Section.

[image]

[Firebase Doc Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: Thanks alot bro ...I'm trying this solution

Answer (score 8):

I guess, you need to update google repository. Try running SDK manager and check if there is any update.

Look at the **comment** in sample [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}
```

> Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have the latest Google
>   Repository in the Android SDK manager

Go to SDK Manager -> Extras and check of updates.

[image: SDK manager's snapshot]

Comment: Thanks alot bro ...I'm trying this solution

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), add this:

```
dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```

In your project level gradle file and this one in the app level gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: thanks Zubair for your help ... I added them before  and i modified the question to include screenshots from my code