# After installing firebase plugnis, not able to build android app using Ionic

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework

I was able to build my App using ionic till I install firebase plugin. Now it shows the following error when I try to build using **2.  cordova build -release android**

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

What went wrong:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
```

Please suggest any solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354611/error27-13-failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-8-0

Comment: Update Android SDK.