# Why isn't shown any log of analytics events on my crashlytics console

Tags: android, firebase, analytics, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm facing a weird crash on my app, I'd like to analyse it better using the firebase crashlytics console by analysing the analytics events that were generated on the section that has crashed. I've seen in documentations and videos that it would happen automatically and these analytics event would be shown at the "logs" tab, but for some reason my crashes don't contain these logs...

Does anyone have some clue of what I should do to make these logs be shown at my "log" tab on the console?

Obs: 
 - The crashes are being displayed on the console without any problem.
 - Below I included an image that shows the exact tab I'm expecting to see these "analytics events". My console is in portuguese, but the "Registros" tab is the "logs" tab in the english version.

[image]

Comment: If your problem is solved, then there is no reason to left the question without a solution!

Comment: The problem isn't solved :/ (I can see only the crash on the console, but the "logs" tab in this crash is empty, that's the problem)

Comment: If you mean your logs in android-studio check which log filter you are chosen for your project.

Comment: That's not what I meant... I meant the tab on the crashlytics that's called "logs". At this tab I'm suppose to see the "analytics events" generated in the section that has crashed.

Comment: Check [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393218/how-to-enable-firebase-crash-reporting-android), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700016/enable-firebase-crash-reporting-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

Fabric/Firebaser here - Google Analytics logs can come through to your Crashlytics sessions as long as you've enabled data sharing between GA and other Firebase products, and we call them breadcrumbs. One thing you can check to make sure nothing obvious is going wrong is your project's Analytics settings. If you head to Project Settings > Integrations > Google Analytics, you can scroll down to the data sharing portion of the integration to ensure that data is being shared between Analytics and other products.

It's also possible that Analytics itself isn't being configured correctly. You can take a look at your console logs to ensure that Analytics is reporting, and [enable debug mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) for more information.

Finally, it's possible that the crash happened before the breadcrumbs were captured. I'd especially expect this to be the culprit if you're noticing other crashes usually have the Analytics information you're expecting.

If you've got any specific questions or issues and the above doesn't help, feel free to [reach out to support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact/) and they should be able to dig into it deeper.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer Kevin, but my project settings seem to be configured correctly according to your instructions... I just read the article you linked, and I read that the analytics keeps the data I registered on the device for about 1 hour and then send the data to the analytics server in order to save battery. Would this data be sent to the analytics' server even though the user kills the app?

Comment: @Kevin: Is that setting moved now with GA4?